# Sending a MongoDB query to a different system: converting to JSON and then decoding into BSON? How to do it in Go language?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, go, bson

I need to transfer a MongoDB query to a different system. For this reason I would like to use the [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). I need this to be done mostly because I use date comparisons in my queries.

So, the kernel of the problem is that I need to transfer a MongoDB query that has been generated in a *node.js* back-end to another back-end written in *Go* language.

Intuitively, the most obvious format for sending this query via *REST*, is JSON. But, MongoDB queries are not exactly JSON, but BSON, which contains special constructs for dates.

So, the idea is to convert the queries into JSON using [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) as form of representation of the special constructs. After some tests it's clear that these queries do not work. Both the MongoDB shell and queries sent via *node.js*'s need the special `ISODate` or `new Date` constructs.

Finally, the actual question: are there functions to encode/decode from JSON to BSON, taking into account [MongoDB Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), both in JavaScript (node.js) and *Go* language?

## Updates

### Node.js encoding package

Apparently [there is a *node.js* package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb-extended-json) that parses and stringifies BSON/JSON.
So, half of my problem is resolved. I wonder if there is something like this in *Go* language.

### Sample query

For example, the following query is in normal BSON:

```
{ Tmin: { $gt: ISODate("2006-01-01T23:00:00.000Z") } }
```

Translated into *MongoDB Extended JSON*, it becomes:

```
{ "Tmin": { "$gt" : { "$date" : 1136156400000 }}}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you post a sample JSON document?

Comment: Sure, I just added a sample BSON query and it's JSON version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found the [mejson](https://github.com/MongoHQ/mejson) library, however it's for Marshaling only, so I decided to write an Unmarshaller.

Behold [ejson](https://github.com/OneOfOne/mgo.ejson) (I wrote it), right now it's a very simple `ejson` -> `bson` converter, there's no `bson` -> `ejson` yet, you can use `mejson` for that.

An [example](http://play.golang.org/p/8dp9BmjVFi):

```
const j = `{"_id":{"$oid":"53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a"},"last_seen_at":{"$date":1405266782008},"display_name":{"$undefined":true},
"ref":{"$ref":"col2", "$id":"53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742b"}}`

type TestS struct {
    Id          bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
    LastSeenAt  *time.Time    `bson:"last_seen_at"`
    DisplayName *string       `bson:"display_name,omitempty"`
    Ref         mgo.DBRef     `bson:"ref"`
}

func main() {
    var ts TestS
    if err := ejson.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &ts); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", ts)

    //or to convert the ejson to bson.M

    var m map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &m); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    err := ejson.Normalize(m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)

}
```