# MongoDB Node JS: Convert between extended JSON and BSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

I'm looking for a function that will convert [extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) objects like,

```
{"foo": {"bar": {"$id": "107531abcssdf091790"}}}
```

to an object with BSON types like,

```
{"foo": {"bar": ObjectID("107531abcssdf091790")}}
```

I can find this in the Java API and the `mongoimport` / `mongoexport` tools, but not in the node API. Anyone know? Thanks much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending a MongoDB query to a different system: converting to JSON and then decoding into BSON? How to do it in Go language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218061/sending-a-mongodb-query-to-a-different-system-converting-to-json-and-then-decod)